# popup menu not showing icons

Tags: android, popupmenu

im trying to build a popup menu with three line in witch every line has title and icon.
but for some reason i dont see the icons. only the title.
this is the XML for the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/editGroup"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
          android:title="Edit group"
          android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/groupSettings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
          android:title="Group settings"
           android:showAsAction="always" />

        <item android:id="@+id/DeleteGroup"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
          android:title="Delete group" />
</menu>
```

and the code that call the menu:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(    MainActivity.this, v);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.group_manu,popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

can anyone help me? how can i place icons in popup menu?

Comment: PopupMenu does not support the icons.

Comment: so how come in the xml i can asign icon? if not on popup menu so how can i pun icons?

Answer (score 1):

Make menu.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:title="Choose Action"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:showAsAction="never">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_edit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
            android:title="Edit group" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:title="Group settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_delete"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:title="Delete group" />
    </menu>
   </item>
</menu>
```

Hope this will help you